# My Entity Class is not properly accepted when inputting to CriteriaQuery.from method

Tags: java

Building a REST API which i want to query MySQL DB and return the result. I am using hibernate for this and using CriteriaBuilder and CriteriaQuery because Session.createCriteria is depreciated.

I have a hibernate.cfg.xml file with the entity class listed. Since CriteriaBuilder is javax.persistence I also added persistence.xml in src/main/java/META-INF but i don't know if i am doing too much and messing up or what

```
sessionObj = HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory().openSession();
sessionObj.beginTransaction();

System.out.println(sessionObj.isConnected());           

System.out.println("1");

CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionObj.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Users> query = builder.createQuery(Users.class);
Root<Users> root = query.from(Users.class);
query.select(root);
Query<Users> q = sessionObj.createQuery(query);
List<Users> employees=q.getResultList();



---- Entity class ----
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "us_prime")
private int usPrima;

@Column(name = "us_id")
private String usId;
```

Comment: What framework or environment are you using to build this? In Spring and some others, most of this is handled for you. In any case, you should be using the JPA interfaces and not the legacy Hibernate interfaces in any new code. Finally... you didn't actually express what your problem is, but if it's the deprecation warnings, use JPA.

Comment: I am using Spring framework for this. The problem is "Root<Users> root = query.from(Users.class);" is throwing an exception saying "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class com.flowManagementSystem.entity.Users". I can't figure out why

Comment: Please post your Users imports, and check if you are using the correct import for @Entity

Comment: import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


import javax.persistence.Column;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;



[@Entity]
[@Table(name = "users")]
public class Users implements Serializable {
 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "us_prime")
private int usPrima;

Comment: Use Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA, and the entire Hibernate interaction will be autogenerated for you. (You'll still supply your entity, of course.)

Comment: do have a project i can reference to get an idea on how to do this? my basic requirement is to create a REST API that will take in a JSON request, query a remote MySQL DB and return the result from the DB as JSON.